# Saving Rolls in T.W.E.R.P.S.: Do you roll versus static number, or make an opposed roll?

Tags: twerps

The rules for Saving Rolls in The World's Easiest Role-Playing System (Dee & Dee, 1987) say:

> A Saving Roll is **just like a roll to hit**, except that the defender is not another character, but rather a "Difficulty Level" from 1 to 10 set by the GM. If the character's total beats the Difficulty total, then the character is successful.

Attack rolls are described as follows:

> To resolve an attack, **the attacker and defender each roll a die** [d10] and total their results with their current Strengths.

The way I've always read this is, the Difficulty Level stands in for Strength, which the GM adds to the result of a d10 roll—an opposed roll. But I see it could possibly be read as a static target number. And in fact, the reviews I've found of the game online treat the DL like a static target number.

Points against treating the "Difficulty Level" as a a static target number include:

- The text above says you win if "the character's total beats the Difficulty **total**"; a "total" implies adding some numbers together.
- The player roll would always beat target numbers from 1–2 when conscious, since they would be adding the result of a d10 roll to their positive Strength number.
- Characters who advance would rapidly get Strength scores that outmatch the highest Difficulty Level—at least, when they are uninjured.

But those points may take the game too seriously, for what it is. Alas, there was too little space in the original rulebook to provide an example.

Answer (score 3):

### They are a simple roll against a 'static' number.

On a safe roll, you roll as if you were attacking someone that defends and rolled the number described as the "Difficulty Level" by the DM. To this number, the GM might add relevant Strengths or effects that modify it for a total.

The result thus would be a static number for each situation or enemy, but it might differ between different situations.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how you reach the conclusion that the "Difficulty total" is a static number? And where is the idea of adding Strengths of other modifiers to the Difficulty Level supported?

If I understand what you're saying, the GM makes up a Difficulty Level, _and then_ adds modifiers to it to form a total. Couldn't the GM just make up a Difficulty Level that incorporates all the factors that would modify it?

Comment: @Gaptooth he could certainly, but then the 1-10 range would be violated. The Difficulty level just takes the place of the other character's roll.